# Distinguish SharedMailboxes and regular mailboxes in Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to make a search field to allow users of my application to search for mailboxes but i want my filter to return only SharedMailBoxes.

So i tried to make my get request as usual and hope that one of the parameters from the returned Microsoft.Graph.User object can allow me to filter my users. e.g userType = sharedmailbox. but none of these parameters seems to indicate the user's type

```
    public static async Task<Users> searchUsers(string token, string search)
    {
        string query = String.Format("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(displayname,'{0}') or startswith(surname,'{1}')", search, search);
        string users = null;
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(query).Result;
        users = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        Users usersJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Users>(users);
        return usersJson;
    }
```

I'm using Microsoft graph v1.0.

Is there a way to find out the type of my user ?

if not. Is there an other API that i'm not aware of that can allow me to manage my SharedMailBoxes and, let's be crazy, also my resource mailboxes ?